# How Can I monitor MySQL Server status

Tags: mysql, azure

**Background**: I have an instance of MySQL 5.7 running on Azure VM (Windows 2012 R2). Every now and then MySQL service stops and I have to manually restart it. I had a look at the logs but could not find anywhere where it says why it stopped. I also had a look at the slow query log and I have since fixed the slow query now.

**My question:** Is there any service /tool that can alert me  if the service has stopped?

Answer (score 1):

Install an inbuilt tool "MySQL Notifier". It comes with the installation package. It will sit on the lower right portion of your server along with clock and will alert you. https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/notifier/

Comment: Thank you for info I did look into mysql notifier but I need something that can notify me via email as I not always logged on the server.

Comment: Links: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic608101-169-1.aspx and https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1663/auto-notification-for-failover-of-a-server-and-restart-of-sql-server-services/

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately both the links are for MSSQL and not for MySQL but they do give me a thought of how to implement it.

Comment: @snowflakes74 The tool I mentioned [Monyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/monyog) provides notification via email. Saved my life all the time. Also, it provides you a lot of other tools that help monitor MySQL. I would suggest that you try it.